# Perl capture groups with logs using regular expressions

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to convert this log line:

```
9:[2019-02-25 00:39:01] production.DEBUG: JOB-VARS : {"phone_numbers":["+9660599291111"],"message":"Your verification code is: 74222","twilio":{},"objectKey":"job:class:App\\Jobs\\SmsJob:000000001328e347000000003113b4f8","connection":"sqs-high","queue":null,"delay":null,"job":{},"JOB-CLASS":"App\\Jobs\\SmsJob"} [] []
16:[2019-02-25 00:50:06] production.DEBUG: JOB-VARS : {"phone_numbers":["+9660533001112"],"message":"Your verification code is: 31231","twilio":{},"objectKey":"job:class:App\\Jobs\\SmsJob:00000000206561fd000000003fb01b05","connection":"sqs-high","queue":null,"delay":null,"job":{},"JOB-CLASS":"App\\Jobs\\SmsJob"} [] []
54:[2019-02-25 03:59:42] production.DEBUG: JOB-VARS : {"phone_numbers":["+9647707771113"],"message":"Your verification code is: 64628","twilio":{},"objectKey":"job:class:App\\Jobs\\SmsJob:0000000003baa9660000000022c0679c","connection":"sqs-high","queue":null,"delay":null,"job":{},"JOB-CLASS":"App\\Jobs\\SmsJob"} [] []
```

into a spreadsheet that looks like this:

```
|       time          |   phone number   |            sms job id          | 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 2019-02-25 00:39:01 | +96605992911111  |000000001328e347000000003113b4f8|
| 2019-02-25 00:50:06 | +96605992911112  |00000000206561fd000000003fb01b05|
| 2019-02-25 03:59:42 | +96605992911113  |0000000003baa9660000000022c0679c|
```

I tried writing this line

```
perl -ne 'print "$1,$2\n" if /\[(.*?)\].+(\[.*\])/' filename
```

but all I got is this:

```
2019-02-25 00:39:01,[]
2019-02-25 00:50:06,[]
2019-02-25 03:59:42,[]
```

I got stuck capturing the second group. Ideas?

Comment: Try [this](https://regex101.com/r/PEKlVy/2)

Comment: Running the same perl command against that file I get some different but expected results. Are you sure the input string is the same as you posted?

Comment: @revo sorry I removed some junk, the actual log file looks like [this](https://gist.github.com/abbood/c2557d2698bff93f5fc18f0edfc47d0b)

Comment: @Potato.. it worked like a charm!

Comment: Note -- you are capturing and printing two things, while three are needed?  Also, I take it that the shown data is correct (and that a bit more that there is on each line, as seen on the link given above, is exactly as seen in that link, not affecting patterns)

Comment: The second pattern in your regex matches the emtpy `[]` at the end of the line (seen in the link, not in the question) because of the greediness of `.+`

Comment: updated question to include actual logs to avoid confusion

Comment: it worked perfectly! i granted you the correct answer

Comment: Great, good to hear it's all good :)   And thank you for taking care of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relying fully on details of the format, with all `"` and `[]` etc

```
perl -wnE'
    say "$1, $2, $3"  
        if /:\[(.*?)\].*?"phone_numbers":\["(.*?)"\].*?SmsJob:(.*?)"/
' file
```

where I use explicit phrases (like `"phone_numbers":`) to anchor needed patterns.

Note the non-greedy patterns everywhere. Since we have convenient textual "anchors" for what we need to capture there is no reason to let greedy patterns run amok; they are much harder to track mentally, can be tricky to get right, and are generally less efficient. <sup>†</sup>

Note that I use `"` after `SmsJob` because `SmsJob:` comes last in `objectKey` and so it happens to have `"` right after, which is handy to delimit the pattern to match. But if that `"` isn't certain to be there then `.*?` need be changed; perhaps to `[0-9a-zA-Z]` (minimal pattern for what is allowed in `SmsJob` value), followed by a literal character that ends it (like `,` or `:` etc).

This captures the timestamp and phone number and SmsJob correctly from the given sample.

---

<sup>†</sup>   The second pattern in the honest attempt in the question fails to capture what is expected because the greedy `.+` grabs *everything* all the way to the very last pair `[]` in the string, since the `\[.*\]` that comes after `.+` does match that last `[]` so the whole pattern matches that way.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this pattern `\[([^\]]++)\].+phone\_numbers\D++(\d++).+SmsJob\:(\w++)`

Explanation:

`\[([^\]]++)\]` will match date inside square brackets, capturing date in a group,

`.+phone\_numbers\D++(\d++)` will match one or more of any characters, then `phone_number` literally, then one or more non-digits and then it will capture actual phone number inside a group with `(\d++)`

`.+SmsJob\:(\w++)` will match first one or more of any characters, then `SmsmJob` literally, then `:` and then will capture job ID inside another capturing group

Answer (score 1):

Your current regex is so greedy and the given input string surely is different. You didn't try to get three capturing groups either. Try this instead:

```
\[([\d: -]+)\][^][]+\["([^][]+)"\].*?SmsJob:(\w+)
```

Perl:

```
perl -ne 'print "$1,$2,$3\n" if /\[([\d: -]+)\][^][]+\["([^][]+)"\].*?SmsJob:(\w+)/' filename
```

Regex breakdown:

- `\[` Match `[` literally
- `(` Start of first capturing group

  - `[\d: -]+` Match a combination of specified characters (digit, `:`, space and `-`)
- `)` End of capturing group
- `\]` Match `]` literally
- `[^][]+` Match anything but `[` and `]`
- `\["` Match `["` literally
- `(` Start of second capturing group

  - `[^][]+` Match anything but `[` and `]`
- `)` End of capturing group
- `"\].*?SmsJob:` Match up to `SmsJob:`
- `(\w+)` Match a sequence of word characters and store in 3rd capturing group

Answer (score 0):

Your "JOB-VARS" look very much like JSON to me. Maybe consider using the JSON module.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use JSON;
my $json= new JSON;
while (<>) {
    my ($ts, $jtext)= /\[(.*?)\] production.DEBUG: JOB-VARS : (.*)/;
    my ($obj)= $json->decode_prefix($jtext);
    my $phone_number= $obj->{phone_numbers}->[0];
    my $jid= $obj->{objectKey};
    $jid=~ s/^.*://;
    printf "| %19s | %-15s |%32s|\n",$ts,$phone_number,$jid;
}
```